# Pandas, quicker way to summarize sub-grouped data totals into merged df as separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pandas-groupby

I have data that I have grouped by two columns and subtotaled.  I used .loc to separate the child group and pd.merge to add each as a column with the totals for the parent group.  This was not an insane amount of typing since there weren't many child groups, but I'm hoping to find a more efficient way for future projects. My code is pretty basic, and I have a habit of doing things the long way, but it feels like there should be a simpler way for larger datasets.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"Company":["a","b","c","b","a","c","a","a","b"], "Product":[3,2,2,1,4,4,3,2,1], "Qty":[2,4,8,1,8,3,6,4,5]}

#Create df and group by first two columns               
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        
grouped_prod_df=df.groupby(["Company","Product"])
        
qty_sum= grouped_prod_df.sum()    
qty_sum_df =pd.DataFrame(qty_sum.reset_index())

# find total qtys of each product
product_1 = qty_sum_df.loc[qty_sum_df["Product"] == 1]
product_2 = qty_sum_df.loc[qty_sum_df["Product"] == 2] 
product_3 = qty_sum_df.loc[qty_sum_df["Product"] == 3]
product_4 = qty_sum_df.loc[qty_sum_df["Product"] == 4]        

product_1_df = pd.DataFrame(product_1)
product_1_df = product_1_df[["Company","Qty"]]
product_1_df = product_1_df.rename(columns={"Qty":"Product_1"})

product_2_df= pd.DataFrame(product_2)
product_2_df = product_2_df[["Company","Qty"]]
product_2_df = product_2_df.rename(columns={"Qty":"Product_2"})

product_3_df= pd.DataFrame(product_3)
product_3_df = product_3_df[["Company","Qty"]]
product_3_df = product_3_df.rename(columns={"Qty":"Product_3"})

product_4_df= pd.DataFrame(product_4)
product_4_df = product_4_df[["Company","Qty"]]
product_4_df = product_4_df.rename(columns={"Qty":"Product_4"})

#sum company grand totals    
company_df = df[["Company","Qty"]]
grouped_company_df=company_df.groupby(["Company"])
company_sum= grouped_company_df.sum()
company_sum_df = pd.DataFrame(company_sum)

#merge product totals in column next to grand total with product as column header and repeat for
#other columns
       
all_prod = pd.merge(company_sum_df, product_1_df, on="Company", how="left")
all_prod = pd.merge(all_prod, product_2_df, on="Company", how="left")
all_prod = pd.merge(all_prod, product_3_df, on="Company", how="left")
all_prod = pd.merge(all_prod, product_4_df, on="Company", how="left")

all_prod
```

EDIT: tried to make my code more generic and ended up not working, but I fixed and tested it now. Output should be the following with Qty showing total of all products by company.

```
Company Qty Product_1   Product_2   Product_3 Product_4
0   a   20  NaN 4   8.0 8.0
1   b   10  6.0 4   NaN NaN
2   c   11  NaN 8   NaN 3.0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your shared code requires fixes (returns a number of errors). Kindly post the expected output and we can work from there.

Comment: It's great that you shared your code and data generation. But could you please elaborate on what you exactly want in plain english too? rather than just code? This way you can be helped better.

Comment: I am looking for a more efficient way to do this where I don't have to specify each product to get product totals in columns and total qty summarizing all products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At it's simplest, you only need to do:

```py
(
    df.groupby(["Company","Product"])
      .sum()
      .unstack(level='Product')['Qty']
      .assign(Qty=lambda df: df.sum(axis='columns'))
)
```

And that'll give you:

```
Product    1    2    3    4   Qty
Company                          
a        NaN  4.0  8.0  8.0  20.0
b        6.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  10.0
c        NaN  8.0  NaN  3.0  11.0
```

If the column names really need to match, you can rename them:

```py
(
    df.groupby(["Company","Product"])
      .sum()
      .unstack(level='Product')['Qty']
      .rename(columns=lambda c: f"Product_{c}")
      .assign(Qty=lambda df: df.sum(axis='columns'))
      .rename_axis(None, axis='columns')
)
```

And that gives you:

```
         Product_1  Product_2  Product_3  Product_4   Qty
Company                                                  
a              NaN        4.0        8.0        8.0  20.0
b              6.0        4.0        NaN        NaN  10.0
c              NaN        8.0        NaN        3.0  11.0
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.